# Not able to print over Ethernet but can over wifi

Tags: networking

[Here is a map of the network (lines are cat5 dashed lines are wifi)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cFFP.jpg)

I'm absolutely stumped with this problem and need help.

The office desktop computer cannot print on the copier (It can't ping it either) through the Ethernet card. If i use a wifi dongle it will work. The office computer can ping the router and the access point but not the copier.

My laptop can ping the copier both through the Ethernet and wifi.

I have disabled the ethernet card and plugged in a wifi card and that seems to work but it slows down my network speed. What do I need to do to print through the Ethernet?

Comment: Are you 100% sure the access point is not a router? In particular, are you 100% sure it's not running a DHCP server? What is the make and model of the device you labelled "access point"? Does it have a WAN port? Is anything connected to it?

Comment: Try turning off IPv6 on the network adapter properties.

Comment: Where is DCHP being handed from? If the router and WAP are both handing it out, that can cause problems. What are the IPs of all the devices?

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure that the copier and router are plugged into LAN ports on the "access point".  Try making sure that the "access point", computer, and laptop are all plugged into LAN ports on the "router".  Don't use a WAN port for any of them.

Make sure they are all in the same subnet.

(There may be other ways to set this up.  I'm only describing one solution, which ought to be rather easy to describe and implement.  It's not eve necessarily the best solution.)

If that doesn't work, then one of the devices isn't acting just like a dumb switch.  Try moving the laptop, and plugging it into a LAN port on the "access point", place it in the same subnet (if it doesn't auto-configure, then commonly, make sure the first three octets of the IPv4 address are the same...  a unique but close IPv4 address is often a good idea).

These steps may get things working, or provide some good hints on how to narrow down the situation to a more specific problem.

Comment: The subnet for everything is the same and I'm only using the LAN ports.

I've connected my laptop to the access point, router, and switch and it can print fine from all those locations. But the desktop computer cannot access the printer if the Ethernet card is enabled. When I disable the ethernet card and plug in a wifi adapter it can print (both when connected directly to the router and when connected to the access point.)

I'm also out of town this weekend so I can't try any changes for a few days.